# Дерганье мыши

Tags: vb6, visual-basic

Уважаемые любители программирования! Помогите написать код в VB чтоб дергался курсор...просто я даже понятия неимею как это должно делаться(((

Comment: Простите моё праздное любопытство -- а зачем вам? А так вообще копайте в сторону WinAPI (`SetCursorPos`?)

Comment: Да у меня тоже вопрос а зачем вам это

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Call SetCursorPos(300, 600)
```